# Upgrading from Elasticseatch 2.x to 5.x

Tags: java, spring, maven, elasticsearch, spring-boot

Having upgrade Elasticsearch 2.x to 5.x , I got the following message in eclipse:

```
The type org.elasticsearch.search.suggest.SuggestBuilder$SuggestionBuilder cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

and here is some snippet code from `pom.xml`

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you got both ES libraries on the classpath and they are mixing together. Check the effective POM and do a proper cleanup. It is also possible that different ES lib is comming as a dependency with one of your other dependencies.